# CSS - Diamond Design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, responsive

## Required Design

[image]

I was wondering how I would go about achieving the attached design properly?

I was thinking

```
<div class="diamond1"><img src="images/diamond1.jpg" alt="diamond" /></div>
<div class="diamond2"><img src="images/diamond2.jpg" alt="diamond" /></div>
<div class="diamond3"><img src="images/diamond3.jpg" alt="diamond" /></div>
etc.......
```

CSS:

```
.diamond1{
   position:absolute;
   top:10px;
   left:40px;
}

etc....
```

Is there a more efficient way of achieving this or will it have to be a meticulous, tedious, media query css job involving absolute positioning?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you just use transform: rotate on the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `transform: rotateZ(45deg);` to rotate your container the way you want it to.

After that it is just a matter of aligning the images. [I made a small demo-pen for that.](https://codepen.io/SourceOverflow/pen/GMENzb)

Note that I used the relative new css-grid. If you want better compatability with older browsers, you might want to use something else. It was just way faster doing it that way than with flexbox.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. I especially like the diamond cage